# How to get full pry debugging session working within chefdk

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, pry, chefdk

I am unable to get the `pry-stack_explorer` and `pry-byebug` gems to work while trying to debug inspec from a `bundle exec` command.

When I open `pry` by itself I have the `show-stack` command available to me.

When I place a `require 'pry'` and `binding.pry` command in inspec and run it with `bundle exec inspec exec some_file.rb`, it does stop me at that point with a `pry` session. However, when I try any of the commands from the byebug or stack_explorer gems, I get an error:

```
[2] pry(#<#<Class:0x00000003ec1910>>)> show-stack NameError: undefined local variable or method `show' for File :#<Class:0x00000003ec1910> from (pry):1:in `initialize
```

I am running within the chefdk embedded version of ruby. My pry-related gems are:

```
ubuntu_machine:~/code/tools/inspec$ chef gem list pry-*

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

pry (0.10.3)
pry-byebug (3.3.0)
pry-doc (0.8.0)
pry-remote (0.1.8)
pry-stack_explorer (0.4.9.2)
```

Why aren't these commands available from within the session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local gems installed on this machine have [in general] nothing to do with your bundle configuration. Please make sure you have `pry-stack_explorer` and `pry-byebug` listed in your `.gemspec` / `Gemfile`, then run `bundle` and retry.